# Accordion ionic resize and scroll

Tags: angularjs, scroll, resize, ionic-framework, accordion

I have an accordion in ionic. To reset the screen size when the user clicks to open one of the items I used `$ionicScrollDelegate.resize();`. However remains a problem, when I click on an item with great content and then click on the item that comes down the content goes up, because closed the item above, but the screen does not scroll together, so the user does not see the content of the item he just clicking.

What I need is that the screen always scroll to the beginning of the contents of the clicked item.

I tried this with

`$IonicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('handle_' + group.id).scrollTop();`

But I must have done something wrong because it returns an error that we could not find the delgate-handle. Searching I found some people saying to use `$timeout` but it also did not solve my problem.

Below is the code I'm using for the controller:

```
.controller('CatalogoCtrl', function($scope, categories, $ionicScrollDelegate) {
  Scope.categorias Categorias.all $ = ();
  $scope.toggleCategoria = function(group) {
    if ($scope.isGroupShown(group)) {
      $scope.shownGroup = null;
    } else {
      $scope.shownGroup = group;
    }
    $IonicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('handle_' + group.id).scrollTop();
  };
  $scope.isGroupShown = function(group) {
    return $scope.shownGroup === group;
  };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a typo in your code, because you have occurrences of $IonicScrollDelegate (starting with an uppercase I) and $ionicScrollDelegate (starting with a lowercase i).

You should therefore change all occurrences of $IonicScrollDelegate to $ionicScrollDelegate.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit